# String Literal Overloading

Tags: c++

Is it possible to make an overload of a constructor which will accept only a blank string when used in an initializer list?

```
struct null_ptr_type;

struct str
{
  str(null_ptr_type*) {}
  str(const char(&)[1]) {}
};

struct config
{
  str s;
};

int main()
{
  config c1 = {0}; // Works, implicit conversion to a null pointer
  config c2 = {str("")}; // Works
  config cx = {str("abc")}; // Fails (as desired)
  config c3 = {""}; // Fails with no conversion possible
}
```

Is there a way to make the syntax for `c3` work without also accepting non-empty strings? I don't see why it doesn't, given that `c1` works. Is there some rule I'm missing here that forbids this?

Comment: FWIW, VS 2013 invokes the implicit conversion as you would expect. Not the best reference I know but it's something.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should specify: `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.7.3`, but good to hear it does work somewhere. :)

Comment: clang++3.5 also accepts this conversion.

Comment: Could you not give it a default value, so you'd do config(string fred = ""); ?

Comment: The real code is much more complex, with members before and after that are initialized. There are also thousands of strings in a format not easily batch-modified. (Lots of legacy code)

Comment: Why do you want this? I can't envision any reason.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, internationalization. This string is displayed to the user, and I want to enforce that all non-empty strings are wrapped in `N_()`, but a lot of those strings are blank strings and I don't want to modify each and every one.

Comment: If N_ is a macro, then you have the option of doing things like `#define N_( s ) tutti_frutti( s, sizeof( s ) )`. In C++03 you could even determine whether `s` was a literal. In C++011 that's only possible with a suitable assumption (clearly communicated to users).

Comment: On further reflection that doesn't solve your problem of "avoid fixing those existing empty strings". Not sure I grok the problem though. It seems strange to have so many empty string arguments around.

Answer (score 0):

Using C++11 and "uniform initialization syntax" you can make this work, on assumption that you are able to modify interface of `struct config`:

```
struct config
{
  str s;

  config(str s) : s(s) {}
};

int main()
{
  config c1 = {0}; // Works, implicit conversion to a null pointer
  config c2 = {str("")}; // Works
  config cx = {str("abc")}; // Fails (as desired)
  config c3 = {""}; // Works
}
```